# PHP back-end not receiving backbone.js POST

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js

Using backbone.js, I call model.save() and through firebug I see that my model's JSON string is indeed POSTed to the model URL.

I tried looking in all variables but couldn't find any data.  $_REQUEST shows POST is the method.
But $_POST is completely empty.

I'm using a very simple PHP page:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

The response to the save/sync call is

```
array
  empty

array
  empty

array
  empty
```

How do I get my PHP back-end to receive the model's JSON string that was POSTed? Any help appreciated thanks.

**Edit**: for anyone interested I did this per Rayno's link:

```
<?php
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
    var_dump($post_vars);
?>
```

Comment: try to return `$_POST` to your js and alert it

Comment: save uses `PUT`. [Access PUT](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Accessing-Incoming-PUT-Data-from-PHP)

Comment: @k102 thanks for the suggestion. I thought I already did that via the var_dumps? Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: how do you deal with the response? i mean smth like `function(responseObject)`.

Comment: @Raynos thanks for the link! I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they're sent to the server? You can check the communication between browser/server with tools like Fiddler or in Firebugs 'Net' console.